# VPN error "Socket bind failed on local address" "Address is already in use"

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'll try not to make this too wordy. I know nothing about Linux or VPN but I'll try to follow instructions and give any additional information you need from me.

I've installed OpenVPN successfully and I set up two VPNs from VPN Gate.

When I try to connect to either VPN I get the same error message - "The VPN connection 'thailand (119.76.45.171)' failed because the connection attempt timed out"

I then got more information on whatever the error was by copy-pasting 'sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog' into the terminal ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q9bo.jpg ). The bit I underlined is the relevant part I believe, correct me if I'm wrong. Someone in an IRC room told me that I already have something assigned to that port.

I couldn't get any more out of IRC (they obviously didn't appreciate how little I know), so I didn't get much further. I got a command line to copy-paste into the terminal that supposedly lists all the devices or programs or whatever that 'listen' to a specified port, pic related (  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTsI5.png ). The first problem I have is that all the items listed seem to be VPN related. Am I missing something? What's the odd one out (if there is one)?

I know I'm demanding a lot, but could anyone give me instructions to follow from here? If you want to explain things or provide links to explanations I'll be happy to read them, but the shortest route would obviously be to give me specific guidelines to follow as I don't understand any of these concepts.

Thanks lads.

Irrelevant(?): I noticed two IP addresses (one before the port number in pic 1, another on the 5th line in pic 2). Have no idea what they are but I guess it's not important.

Answer (score 0):

Stop `openvpn` service. It probably started at boot-time.

Then try to start manually with:

```
openvpn server.conf
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try to start it using that method

http://i.imgur.com/CsBPCdH.jpg

it tells me I can get more info with '--help' but when I try that it appears to give me a bunch of irrelevant details. It goes on for a lot longer than in pic.

Is there any way I can dump all the text given back to me without hitting the character limit?

Comment: I also noticed pic related among to feedback given to me using 'openvpn --help' http://i.imgur.com/9M9PSk1.png

I won't touch these unless someone tells me to because I don't wanna dig an even deeper hole for myself, but is it possible to resolve the issue by using one of these commands to just select a different port?

Thanks my man.